# Where do I suggest something related to the default GTK theme(s)?

Tags: themes, design

I just wanted to know where to suggest a change related to the default themes.

Answer (score 1):

[On the `light-themes` page at Launchpad.](https://launchpad.net/light-themes)

If it's possibly an error, file a bug report. If it's a change you *wish* to see, file the report as a wishlist.

Comment: On Launchpad, *Wishlist* is a bug **importance** that is applied by a triager (or developer) after a bug is filed. Unlike bug **status**, users not officially affiliated with a project cannot set a bug's **importance**. You can, however, make clear that your report is a feature request, using language like, "This is a feature request for..."

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu items regarding the user experience are often discussed by the Ayatana project.

Their home page is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana). I'm confident they concern themselves with just about anything regarding the aesthetics of Ubuntu use.